# Perl IO::Handle warn behavior

Tags: perl

I just ran into a nasty little bug with something I was doing because I opened a file for input and not output (that's not the nasty part). It happened because I was using XML::Writer, which can take either a blessed IO::Handle reference or a filehandle for output (or a scalar ref, but that's not important here). Internally, XML::Writer calls `->print` on whatever output ref it's using.

The problem arose because it's possible to call `print` on a filehandle that's been opened only for input, and IO::Handle doesn't warn at all. Here's some code to illustrate:

```
open my $out, '<', 'out.txt';
say $out 'testing';         # warns, "Filehandle opened only for input"
$out->print('testing');     # doesn't do anything?!

open my $out2, '>', 'out2.txt';
$out2->print('testing');    # works fine
```

What's going on here? Is this expected behavior? I don't use the IO:: classes a whole lot, so am I just misunderstanding something?

Edit for clarity:

The code above definitely produces one warning (line 2). I feel like line 3 should also produce a warning, but it doesn't. It doesn't print anything to `$out`, nor does it warn that it doesn't...it simply fails silently (which seems wrong). Line 3 doesn't produce a warning on any version of Perl I have: 5.8, 5.10, or 5.16.

Comment: What version of Perl and `IO::Handle` do you have? I get the warning with Perl 5.14.2.

Comment: I'm running Perl v5.16.0 and IO::Handle v1.33. The code above does produce one warning, but it should (I think) produce two; `$out->print` should warn if it's not opened for output.

Comment: I get the warning with Perl 5.10.1

Comment: Wow.  Yeah, that's weird.  (On 5.10.1, I get the `say` warning but not any `print` warning.)

Comment: 5.16.2 & Handle v1.33:  I get 2 warnings from Lines 430 & 417 of Handle.pm .  If I `use v5.16` then the 1st warning is reported from the program itself instead of from Handle.

Comment: XML::Writer should probably check the return value of `$fh->print`.

Comment: Did you try to look for difference between `perl -w` and `use warnings`? It looks like inside vs. outside warning, to me.

Answer (score 0):

All version >=5.14 do warn correctly on the third line, the FH method call.

Versions 5.10 and 5.12 do warn differently:
*Can't locate object method "print" via package "IO::File".* 
This is because there printing to an input-only handle is not defined.
You need the `print <$out>;` syntax there for printing the result of an input-handle read.

Versions <5.10 don't have say, but would warn the same as 5.10 and 5.12.